# Azure Devops Build pipeline NuGet pack fails (.net core 5)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

As inuitive and handy setting up build pipelines is, I cannot figure out how to get a nuget package created after building. I am not using .yml.
Project is .Net Core 5.

[image]

This is the log:

```
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\a\1\s\Package\SomeCompanyPackages.0.0.1.nupkg' because it is being used by another process.

   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
Id: SomeCompanyPackages
   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
Version: 0.0.1
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildPackage(PackageBuilder builder, String outputPath, Boolean symbolsPackage)
Authors: VssAdministrator
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildFromProjectFile(String path)
Description: Description
   at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.ExecuteCommand()
Dependencies: 
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.ExecuteCommandAsync()

   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
Added file '[Content_Types].xml'.
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args)
Added file '_rels/.rels'.
Added file 'SomeCompanyPackages.nuspec'.
Added file 'lib/net5.0/SomeCompanyPackages.dll'.
Added file 'package/services/metadata/core-properties/d9f19903a89841ee8740535a9eba2337.psmdcp'.

##[error]The nuget command failed with exit code(1) and error(Error NU5115: Description was not specified. Using 'Description'.
Error NU5115: Author was not specified. Using 'VssAdministrator'.
Error NU5128: Some target frameworks declared in the dependencies group of the nuspec and the lib/ref folder do not have exact matches in the other location. Consult the list of actions below:
- Add a dependency group for net5.0 to the nuspec
The process cannot access the file 'D:\a\1\s\Package\SomeCompanyPackages.0.0.1.nupkg' because it is being used by another process.
System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'D:\a\1\s\Package\SomeCompanyPackages.0.0.1.nupkg' because it is being used by another process.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.InternalDelete(String path, Boolean checkHost)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildPackage(PackageBuilder builder, String outputPath, Boolean symbolsPackage)
   at NuGet.Commands.PackCommandRunner.BuildFromProjectFile(String path)
   at NuGet.CommandLine.PackCommand.ExecuteCommand()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.ExecuteCommandAsync()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Command.Execute()
   at NuGet.CommandLine.Program.MainCore(String workingDirectory, String[] args))
##[error]An error occurred while trying to pack the files.
Finishing: NuGet pack
```

UPDATE:
just found out that there is another (newer) way to pack nu get packages.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops
Unfortunately this seems to be only available for yml config.
How can I add this to my configuration? There is no **.NET Core CLI task** available in task library for agent.

Comment: There is but i think you looked for the wrong name. The task is called ".NET Core", not ".NET Core CLI"

Answer (score 0):

with respect to comment by D.J.

One solution is to add not one but two additional taks of type **.NET Core**

1. pack
2. push

Hope this helps newbies like me to get it running without spending hours of reading documentations that don't cover this after all.

[image]